# Issues with postgresql-11 partitioning and primary key autoincrement

Tags: database-partitioning, postgresql-11

Primary key on partitioned tables is incremented by n(n>1) and not by 1.

Tried to rewrite plpgsql in numerous different ways with no luck.
There must be something I am not understanding.

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS some_record_pool;

CREATE SEQUENCE some_record_pkey_seq;

create table some_record
(
    id BIGINT not null DEFAULT nextval('some_record_pkey_seq'::regclass),
    device_id bigint,
    device_type bigint,
    record_time timestamp,
    module_serial_number bigint,
    module_id bigint,
    message_type bigint,
    event_code bigint,
    device_status bytea,
    sequence_number bigint,
    data_bytes bigint,
    device_data bytea,
    active boolean,
    deleted boolean,
    created_time timestamp default now() not null,
    created_on timestamp with time zone default now() not null,
    updated_on timestamp with time zone default now() not null
);


CREATE INDEX idx_device_id
    ON public.some_record USING brin
    (device_id)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX idx_module_id
    ON public.some_record USING brin
    (module_id)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX idx_er_created_time
    ON public.some_record (cast(created_time as DATE));

----- CREATE TRIGGER ----------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_record_insert_function()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    partition_date    TEXT;
    partition_name    TEXT;
    start_of_month    TEXT;
    end_of_next_month TEXT;
BEGIN
    partition_date := to_char(NEW.created_time, 'YYYY_MM');
    partition_name := 'some_record_' || partition_date;
    start_of_month := to_char((NEW.created_time), 'YYYY-MM') || '-01';
    end_of_next_month := to_char((NEW.created_time + interval '1 month'), 'YYYY-MM') || '-01';
    IF NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1
         FROM information_schema.tables
         WHERE table_name = partition_name)
    THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'A partition has been created %', partition_name;
        EXECUTE format(
                E'CREATE TABLE some_record_pool.%I ' ||
                E'(CHECK ( date_trunc(\'day\', created_time) >= ''%s'' ' ||
                E'AND date_trunc(\'day\', created_time) < ''%s'')) INHERITS (public.some_record)',
                partition_name, start_of_month, end_of_next_month);
        -- EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT ON TABLE %I TO readonly',
        -- partition_name); -- use this if you use role based permission
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'A partition DOES NOT EXIST %', partition_name;
    END IF;
    EXECUTE format(
            'INSERT INTO some_record_pool.%I (device_id, device_type, ' ||
            'record_time, module_serial_number, module_id, message_type, ' ||
            'event_code, device_status, sequence_number, data_bytes, device_data,' ||
            ' active, deleted) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13)',
            partition_name) using NEW.device_id, NEW.device_type,
        NEW.record_time, NEW.module_serial_number, NEW.module_id, NEW.message_type,
        NEW.event_code, NEW.device_status, NEW.sequence_number, NEW.data_bytes,
                NEW.device_data, NEW.active, NEW.deleted;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER insert_some_record_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON public.some_record
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.some_record_insert_function();

--- INSERTING DATA FOR TESTING

INSERT INTO some_record (
    event_record_id, timestamp, event_description_id, event_source_label, event_source_track, event_source_direction, 
    measurement_description, measurement_value, hw_address_module_id, hw_address_rlc_address, sub_system_source, 
    event_type, device_id, active, deleted) VALUES(1, 2, to_timestamp('1953-10-21 14:30:46.555337', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.US'), 1, 1, 1, 1, NULL, 1, 9, E'9 B
00000000  92 FF 3C 00 7F 00 00 03 E8                         .ÿ<.....è
', TRUE, FALSE, to_timestamp('2019-10-21 14:30:46.555337', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.US'), to_timestamp('2019-10-21 14:30:46.555337', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.US'));
```

The point of the code is to auto create partitions and insert data if partition exists.

Primary key should be incremented by one but it is not behaving as such
expected output on only one run is id: 1

Answer (score 0):

Working solution tested on postgres 12 is the following:

```
/** TABLE PARTITIONING EVENT RECORD **/

-- CREATE PROPER SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test_par_pool;

-- CREATE PROPER TABLE

CREATE TABLE test_part
(
    id                   bigserial                              not null
        constraint test_part_pkey
            primary key,
    device_id            bigint,
    device_type          bigint,
    record_time          timestamp,
    module_serial_number bigint,
    module_id            bigint,
    message_type         bigint,
    event_code           bigint,
    device_status        bytea,
    sequence_number      bigint,
    data_bytes           bigint,
    device_data          bytea,
    active               boolean,
    deleted              boolean,
    created_time         timestamp                default now() not null,
    created_on           timestamp with time zone default now() not null,
    updated_on           timestamp with time zone default now() not null
);


-- CREATE MINIMAL INDEXES
CREATE INDEX idx_device_id
    ON public.test_part USING brin
    (device_id)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX idx_module_id
    ON public.test_part USING brin
    (module_id)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX idx_er_created_time
    ON public.test_part (cast(created_time as DATE));

-- CREATE INSERT FUNCTIONS

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_par_insert_function()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    partition_date    TEXT;
    partition         TEXT;
    start_of_month    TEXT;
    end_of_next_month TEXT;
    stmt              TEXT;
BEGIN
    partition_date := to_char(NEW.created_time, 'YYYY_MM');
    partition := TG_RELNAME || '_' || partition_date;
    start_of_month := to_char((NEW.created_time), 'YYYY-MM') || '-01';
    end_of_next_month := to_char((NEW.created_time + interval '1 month'), 'YYYY-MM') || '-01';
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname = partition) THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'A partition has been created %',partition;
        stmt = 'CREATE TABLE test_par_pool.' || partition || ' (check (date_trunc(''day'', created_time) >= '
                   || chr(39) || start_of_month || chr(39)
                   || ' AND date_trunc(''day'', created_time) < '
                   || chr(39) || end_of_next_month
                   || chr(39) || ' )) INHERITS ( public.' || TG_RELNAME ||
               ');';
        EXECUTE stmt;
    END IF;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO test_par_pool.' || partition ||
            ' SELECT( public.' || TG_RELNAME || ' ' || quote_literal(NEW) || ').* RETURNING id;';
    RETURN NULL;

END
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- CREATE TRIGGER

CREATE TRIGGER insert_test_part_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON public.test_part
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.test_par_insert_function();
```